# Microsoft batch file not passing arguments to subroutine

Tags: windows, batch-file, ftp, arguments

The following batch file is not correctly passing the variables %%a, %%b, %%c to subroutine correctly.

```
@echo off
enter code here`setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

FOR /F "tokens=1,2,3 delims= " %%a in (ftp_config.txt) do (
  echo %%a
  echo %%b
  echo %%c
  call :SUB_ftp_cmd %%a %%b %%c
  )
exit

:SUB_ftp_cmd
echo open %1>ftp.txt
echo %2>>ftp.txt
echo %3>>ftp.txt
echo cd /public_html>>ftp.txt
echo bin>>ftp.txt
echo hash>>ftp.txt
echo put "test.txt">>ftp.txt
echo close>>ftp.txt
echo bye>>ftp.txt

c:\windows\system32\ftp.exe -i <ftp.txt

del ftp.txt

exit /b
```

ftp.config contains the following:

```
domain_name1 username1 password1
domain_name2 username2 password2
```

The content of ftp.txt ends up being:

```
open 
ECHO is off.
ECHO is off.
cd /public_html
bin
hash
put "test.txt"
close
bye
```

I've put a few lines in as debug and see that %%a, %%b, %%c are being assigned correctly in the FOR loop, but are not passed to SUB_ftp_cmd correctly.

Updated the batch file to:

```
@echo off
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
FOR /F "tokens=1,2,* delims=      " %%a in (ftp_config.txt) do (
  echo(=== for loop variables: a=[%%a], b=[%%b], c=[%%c]
    set "passw=%%c"
    call :SUB_ftp_cmd %%a %%b
  )
exit /B

:SUB_ftp_cmd
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
>ftp.txt (
echo open %1
echo(%2
echo(!passw!
echo cd /public_html
echo bin
echo hash
echo put "test.txt"
echo close
echo bye
)
ENDLOCAL
echo(=== ftp.txt content
type ftp.txt
echo(=== ftp command is merely displayed using `ECHO`
ECHO c:\windows\system32\ftp.exe -i -s:ftp.txt
echo(
rem del ftp.txt
exit /b
```

ftp_config.txt has:

```
"ftp.domain1.com" username1 pas3&^#%$
"ftp.domain2.com" username2 passworks
```

resulting ftp.txt:

```
open "ftp.domain2.com"
username2

cd /public_html
bin
hash
put "test.txt"
close
bye
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `ftp /?` says that one should use `ftp -i -s:ftp.txt` instead of `ftp.exe -i <ftp.txt`. However, your script might run properly using `setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion` to keep possible `!` exclamation mark(s) in password. And I'd use `FOR /F "tokens=1,2,*" %%a in (ftp_config.txt) do …` and `call :SUB_ftp_cmd %%a %%b "%%c"` and `echo %~3>>ftp.txt`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can reproduce very similar results if there is an *seemingly empty* line in the `ftp_config.txt` file even thought it contains (one or more) `<tab>` (Character Tabulation). 
Let's argue against `"tokens=1,2,3 delims= "` clause:

- If you specify `"delims=<space>"` ([Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) codepoint `U+0020`) then `for /F` tokenization will fail for `<tab>` (codepoint `U+0009`) and vice versa.
- [If you don’t specify `delims` it will default to `"delims=<tab><space>"`](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html).
- Hence, you could specify `"tokens=1,2,*"` omitting `delims` at all.
- Unfortunately, there is another extra *invisible* space-like character   (*No-Break Space*, codepoint `U+00A0`) which is not a valid delimiter.

Conclusion: use `"delims=<tab><No-Break Space><space>"`; in terms of keyboard input (I don't know better way how-to show it here): "delims=<kbd>Tab</kbd><kbd>Alt+0160</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd>".

Next script should work even if a password contains [`cmd` poisonous characters or valid delimiters](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html) like `%`, `&`, `|`, `<`, `>`, `!`, `,`, `;`, `=` etc. (supposing that computer and user names don't contain those ones), see output below:

```
@echo off
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
rem FOR /F "tokens=1,2,*" %%a in (ftp_config.txt) do (
rem in next line     delims=<tab><No-Break Space><space>" %%a …
FOR /F "tokens=1,2,* delims=      " %%a in (ftp_config.txt) do (
  echo(=== for loop variables: a=[%%a], b=[%%b], c=[%%c]
    set "passw=%%c"
    call :SUB_ftp_cmd %%a %%b
  )
exit /B

:SUB_ftp_cmd
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
>ftp.txt (
echo open %1
echo(%2
echo(!passw!
echo cd /public_html
echo bin
echo hash
echo put "test.txt"
echo close
echo bye
)
ENDLOCAL
echo(=== ftp.txt content
type ftp.txt
echo(=== ftp command is merely displayed using `ECHO`
ECHO c:\windows\system32\ftp.exe -i -s:ftp.txt
echo(
del ftp.txt
exit /b
```

**Output**:

```
==> D:\bat\SO\37648941.bat
=== for loop variables: a=[domain_name1], b=[username1], c=[pass&,!%word1]
=== ftp.txt content
open domain_name1
username1
pass&,!%word1
cd /public_html
bin
hash
put "test.txt"
close
bye
=== ftp command is merely displayed using `ECHO`
c:\windows\system32\ftp.exe -i -s:ftp.txt

=== for loop variables: a=[domain_name2], b=[username2], c=[pass<;!%word2]
=== ftp.txt content
open domain_name2
username2
pass<;!%word2
cd /public_html
bin
hash
put "test.txt"
close
bye
=== ftp command is merely displayed using `ECHO`
c:\windows\system32\ftp.exe -i -s:ftp.txt

==>
```

Comment: Thanks JosefZ, this solved passing the domain_name and username, however, I'm still getting "ECHO is off." for the line that should contain the password. The ftp_config.txt file contains no tabs only spaces. The password does contain some special characters [! | ^ | etc.], any other requirements I need to handle password correctly?

Comment: @ruaok See my updated answer, pay heed to left parenthesis in both `echo(%2` and `echo(!passw!`. This should produce an empty output line suppressing `ECHO is off` message in case of `%2` or `!passw!` is empty. Please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/37648941/edit) and add [mcve] of your `ftp_config.txt` and corresponding output like I do in my answer.

Comment: Hi JosefZ, I appreciate the detailed attention you have given. I updated the questions with the edits you gave and am still seeing some issue with the password. Adding the left parenthesis in both echo(%2 and echo(!passw! changed the result to have an empty line for the password in the ftp.txt

Comment: Pay your attention to the `echo(=== for loop variables: a=[%%a], b=[%%b], c=[%%c]` line. It's here but just for debugging purposes…

Comment: Specify `"tokens=1,2,*"` omitting `delims` at all. If the output wouldn't be correct then please **ensure** that you use `"delims=<tab><No-BreakSpace><space>"`. Note that some text editors tend to expand `<tab>` to spaces!

Comment: Thanks very much. Removing delims solved the issue with `set "passw=%%c"`. Any ideas on how I can download the file test.txt for each iteration and write the content of the file out to a log?

Comment: @ruaok sorry, the last exceeds your question topic. Please ask another one. If my answer was helpful, please consider marking it as accepted. [See this page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/) for an explanation of why this is important.